# Google Ads are not displayed when using VPN

Tags: linux, vpn, wireguard, advertisements

I launched VPN for personal usage with Wireguard. But for a reason I cannot see Google Ads and some other scripts are blocked because of CSP violation.

Everything works fine if I'm using Psiphon or WARP.
On server I'm using Alpine Linux and Wireguard.

server config:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.20.30.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = key
MTU = 1400
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT

[Peer]
PublicKey = key
PresharedKey = key
AllowedIPs = 10.20.30.2/32
```

client config

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.20.30.2/32
PrivateKey = key
DNS = 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
MTU = 1400

[Peer]
PublicKey = key
PresharedKey = key
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = server_ip:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 15
```

I tried to use browser extension to disable CSP, but it doesn't work

Comment: VPN shouldn't affect how CSP is implemented, but they *might* be blocking ads/trackers through DNS settings and show their default blocking page, which the CSP then throws tantrum because it's getting invalid content.

Comment: @Martheen how can I check it? I'm using Google DNS on my Wi-Fi router (and it works well) and I'm using it on my wireguard configuration but I have this problem

Comment: Check the blocked URLs from browser console and compare the domain resolution when using VPN and not using it, plus try to navigate to those URLs directly and see what you get, with the VPN toggled on and off.

Comment: Actually I compared all logs from console in Chrome and Firefox and turned out they are same for Psiphon and my VPN. But I installed unbound DNS server on my VPS and I see it in nslookup. So I don't really know why I don't see these ads and what to check because logs are same (errors and warnings), network tab with same amount of queries and same statuses